# akka-contrib: Issue with upgrading akka library version to 2.6.20

Tags: scala, akka

I'm upgrading akka library versions from v2.5.23 to v2.6.20 in a scala application. I'm also using akka-contrib library and I could not find a suitable version that is compatible with other akka libraries. akka-contrib v2.5.32 is the latest version I could see from maven. I'm getting the below error while running the application.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are using version
> 2.6.20 of Akka, but it appears you (perhaps indirectly) also depend on older versions of related artifacts. You can solve this by adding an
> explicit dependency on version 2.6.20 of the [akka-persistence,
> akka-protobuf, akka-cluster-tools] artifacts to your project. Here's a
> complete collection of detected artifacts: (2.5.32,
> [akka-cluster-tools, akka-persistence, akka-protobuf]), (2.6.20,
> [akka-actor, akka-cluster, akka-coordination, akka-pki,
> akka-protobuf-v3, akka-remote, akka-slf4j, akka-stream]). See also:
> https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/common/binary-compatibility-rules.html#mixed-versioning-is-not-allowed

I need to find a version of akka-contrib that is compatible with other akka libraries(v.2.6.20). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/akka/akka/commit/048a04b19304506ee9d8b83a8a1e8f6d2b7ba1e4 - Akka Contrib was deprecated and in 2.6 it simply doesn't exists as a module in Akka repository.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok, could you say what will be the replacement for this library?

Comment: [pekko](https://pekko.apache.org/)? :)

Comment: @Tim, will there be a lot of code changes if I move to pekko. Anyways! will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: @Gokulkrishnan Switching core libraries from akka to pekko is mostly just renaming imports, but any support libraries that use akka are more problematic (e.g. sangria), so worth checking before jumping in!

Comment: In the commit I linked there are replacements listed for each types from the library: some are moved to core Akka, some require copy-pasting some implementation, but there is no single library to replace it all.

Comment: As a matter of the fact: if you are updating from 2.5 you must have seen the deprecation and decide to ignore/suppress them. 2.5 docs have a section about [akka-contrib](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/project/migration-guide-2.4.x-2.5.x.html#contrib) (the same as I linked before).